# Make container of inline blocks (that is inline-block on its own) to wrap its contents into 2 lines while resizing

Tags: html, css

I have quite an interesting problem in front of me. I think it would be better to illustrate it in codepen:

https://codepen.io/BooleT/pen/bWdPWe/

In the class names ib means "inline-block" and iib means "inner inline block".

I have created figures to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. In the next 3 paragraphs I will reference the images in this album:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpc74.jpg

So there are three inline blocks, one of which is actually a container of three other inline-blocks:

[image: 1st image]

The effect I want to achieve is to make the contents of the container to wrap into 2 lines when I resize the window:

[image: 2nd image]

But instead I only manage to wrap the whole container itself to the second line:

[image: 3rd image]

Is there actually the way to achieve what I want? I've tried to add nbsp between outer inline-blocks and to add `white-space: nowrap` to the body element (and overwrite it to `white-space: normal` for the container), but none of it worked.
I know that I can work around it by adding media-queries or js that simply reduces the width (or max-width) of the container when I reduce the screen width, but it doesn't seem like the solution. I don't even know the width of every block in my real layout.

I will try to keep an open mind, since the solution to this problem might require to change the entire layout of the page, but I do think there is one.

Comment: @Santi, no, I think you don't understand what I am trying to do. I WANT the container to be in line with the two left blocks. But at the same time I want its inner inline blocks to render in two, or even three lines if there's not enough width on the screen to render them in one. Instead, I get the whole container to jump on the next line.

Comment: If you are okay with using JavaScript this shouldn't be too complicated. You could resize the container to whatever value is large between the width available for the third outer block and the width of the largest inner block, every time the window is resized.

Comment: @11684 yeah, I thought about it, but the problem is that I don't even know the actual width of the contents inside the container. Of cause, I can measure it using the same javascript, but come on...

Comment: Can you use flexbox?

Comment: @BooleT What's wrong with that? The rendered width of the element is readily available in `element.offsetWidth`.

Comment: @mrmcgreg yes I can. Is there an elegant solution using flex? Didn't work with them too much before.

Comment: @11684, yeah, but it seems like a hack. I will still use it though if nothing more "elegant" will come up.

Comment: Does this work? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVWwEP

Comment: @mrmcgreg yes! seems like exactly what I want. You can publish this codepen as the answer and I will mark it as the final one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use flexbox then this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVWwEP seems like it does what you want. Be aware of the [compatibility caveats](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) that go along with flexbox, though.

For convenience I've put `display: flex;` on the `body` to create top level row, although @10nikov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458093/285915) is definitely a better way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Being not a fan of flexboxes – the burden of old-browser compatibility still standing strong where I come from – here's what we do to make a container on the right occupy all the remaining horizontal space: 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVWwPO)

The fixed-size divs on the left are told to be `float: left`.
The spanning div on the right is given `display: block`.
The smallest inner divs are `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks! This is not the perfect solution, but the closest to one. I will sleep on this problem, and if by the morning nothing better will come up, I will mark this answer as the final one.

Comment: Slight improvement: the third div should also be given `overflow: hidden`. This way items in third column will visually remain inside the third column instead of floating below the first column. **https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmbGag**